# How to store JSON data from Github Gist to an array with AJAX method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, ajaxform

I am trying to store JSON data in a variable, later randomly access it. (Random Superhero Name)

JSON data is GitHub gist below

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abroroo/004fa0a28b94bc7100b4f1bf53acb69d/raw/09fd4ca4ed1ddb21010a48502cf0846a844b658c/authors.json

I am trying to use the ajax method(first time), and I think it is not working. I am getting undefined in the console.

Here is my code:

```
var namesData;

function getNames() {
  return $.ajax({
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abroroo/004fa0a28b94bc7100b4f1bf53acb69d/raw/09fd4ca4ed1ddb21010a48502cf0846a844b658c/authors.json',
    success: function (jsonNames) {
        namesData = JSON.parse(jsonNames);
        console.log('namesData');
        console.log(namesData);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the function to get random names

```
function getRandomName() {
  return namesData.names[
    Math.floor(Math.random() * namesData.names.length)
  ];
}
console.log(getRandomName());
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try adding the error message to see what error is being returned. Or check your browser console if you're running this in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked you gist json file,it has syntax error.
the origin json is

```json
[
  "names": [
    {
        "superhero":"Batman", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Bruce Wayne",
        "first_appearance":"Detective Comics #27",
        "characters":"Bruce Wayne"
    },
```

there should not have key under `array`.so change root array to dict like this

```json
{
  "names": [
    {
        "superhero":"Batman", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Bruce Wayne",
        "first_appearance":"Detective Comics #27",
        "characters":"Bruce Wayne"
    },
```

Comment: Still not working. Maybe I have some errors in my code!? Can you have a look at my codepen, please? 
https://codepen.io/abroro/pen/dyWpGXL?editors=0002
I am building random jokes generator with a random superhero author for this joke. Ajax method is working with joke json gist data, but not working with superhero gist.

Comment: hey,I checked the code and fix the bug.https://codepen.io/nay-kang/pen/gOWGmPL?editors=0002.I have comment and point the problem.the main problem is you should use data after ajax finished

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Appreciate that.  So the error was triggered because I declared console.log before ajax finished?

Comment: yes,before ajax finished,the `namesData` is Null,do not have attribute `names`.so if you use that attribute,it will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an Object in a Array body. You can modity the json as this.

```js
{ 
  "names":[
    {
        "superhero":"Batman", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Bruce Wayne",
        "first_appearance":"Detective Comics #27",
        "characters":"Bruce Wayne"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Superman", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Kal-El",
        "first_appearance":"Action Comics #1",
        "characters":"Kal-El"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Flash", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Jay Garrick",
        "first_appearance":"Flash Comics #1",
        "characters":"Jay Garrick, Barry Allen, Wally West, Bart Allen"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Green Lantern", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Alan Scott",
        "first_appearance":"All-American Comics #16",
        "characters":"Alan Scott, Hal Jordan, Guy Gardner, John Stewart, Kyle Raynor, Jade, Sinestro, Simon Baz"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Green Arrow", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Oliver Queen",
        "first_appearance":"More Fun Comics #73",
        "characters":"Oliver Queen"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Wonder Woman", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Princess Diana",
        "first_appearance":"All Star Comics #8",
        "characters":"Princess Diana"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Martian Manhunter", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"J'onn J'onzz",
        "first_appearance":"Detective Comics #225",
        "characters":"Martian Manhunter"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Robin/Nightwing", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Dick Grayson",
        "first_appearance":"Detective Comics #38",
        "characters":"Dick Grayson"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Blue Beetle", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Dan Garret",
        "first_appearance":"Mystery Men Comics #1",
        "characters":"Dan Garret, Ted Kord, Jaime Reyes"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Black Canary", 
        "publisher":"DC Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Dinah Drake",
        "first_appearance":"Flash Comics #86",
        "characters":"Dinah Drake, Dinah Lance"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Spider Man", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Peter Parker",
        "first_appearance":"Amazing Fantasy #15",
        "characters":"Peter Parker"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Captain America", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Steve Rogers",
        "first_appearance":"Captain America Comics #1",
        "characters":"Steve Rogers"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Iron Man", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Tony Stark",
        "first_appearance":"Tales of Suspense #39",
        "characters":"Tony Stark"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Thor", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Thor Odinson",
        "first_appearance":"Journey into Myster #83",
        "characters":"Thor Odinson"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Hulk", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Bruce Banner",
        "first_appearance":"The Incredible Hulk #1",
        "characters":"Bruce Banner"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Wolverine", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"James Howlett",
        "first_appearance":"The Incredible Hulk #180",
        "characters":"James Howlett"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Daredevil", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Matthew Michael Murdock",
        "first_appearance":"Daredevil #1",
        "characters":"Matthew Michael Murdock"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Hawkeye", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Clinton Francis Barton",
        "first_appearance":"Tales of Suspense #57",
        "characters":"Clinton Francis Barton"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Cyclops", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Scott Summers",
        "first_appearance":"X-Men #1",
        "characters":"Scott Summers"
    },
    {
        "superhero":"Silver Surfer", 
        "publisher":"Marvel Comics", 
        "alter_ego":"Norrin Radd",
        "first_appearance":"The Fantastic Four #48",
        "characters":"Norrin Radd"
    } 
  ]
}
```

Change the Brackets to  curly braces

Comment: Still not working. Can you have a look at my code on codepen, please? I am building random jokes generator with a random superhero author for this joke. 
Ajax method is working with joke json gist data, but not with superhero gist.

Here is my codepen:  
https://codepen.io/abroro/pen/dyWpGXL?editors=0002